# windows phone emulator is doing complete OS reboot

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-7, windows-mobile, emulation

can someone with expertise help me in this regard? I've tried every possible way, even tried re-installing...couldn't get rid of this error on emulator. Unfortunately i cannot try re-instaling OS on my laptop. I use win7 32 bit OS.

emulator shows "windows phone emulator is doing complete OS reboot.." and then crashes, emulator comesup again. This repeats for 3 times and the i can see error "The RPC server unavailable"

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you by any chance running the emulator (XDE) inside a virtual machine?

Comment: no, running on windows7 laptop. No VM involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minimum ram required is 3GB, i was having only 2GB, hence the problem(i think).
I upgraded to 4GB and now it works fine, still open questions are
1) why i was allowed to install 7.1?
2) why it was working for sometime without any issue?

Comment: I am having only 1 GB Ram, do i seriously need to upgrade?